# Excel VBA, Get number of copies to print

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Workbook_BeforePrint event in ThisWorkbook to capture the print event.

How do I get the user's print options before the Print button is clicked.  I want to know what page the user wants to print and how many copies.

I know how to set it (i.e.:Worksheets("Sheet1").PrintOut From:=2, To:=3) but how do you get it from VBA?

Here's what I need to do:

If {page to print} > 2 and {number of copies requested} > 1 Then
   ... do something ...
End If

Thanks

Comment: Is this not an option for you?.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21506688/get-printer-options-in-excel-vba

Comment: Not really.  I'm looking for the pages to print and the number of copies requested.  I've added some additional info in question.

Comment: this is a great question. it is difficult because the "data packet" that will be sent to the printer, is not inside of the print form nor has it been sent to the printer spool. I am not sure how it is being stored. Maybe saved as a temp file somewhere? It will have to be found and read.